# Trouble with a Firebase Query

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am new to firebase because parse is shutting down and I have spent days trying to figure out how to find the parent of the child I am trying to query. For example let's say my parent is email and my child is person1. Now in my dictionary person1 is paired with person 1(there is a complicated reason why I am doing this but it is not a problem)

So my code looks like this.

```
   Firebase *fb=[[Firebase alloc]initWithUrl:@"https:firebaseURL"];
    [[[fb queryOrderedByChild:@"person1 string"] queryEqualToValue:@"person1 string"]
    observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
     NSLog(@"888888%@", snapshot.key);
 }];
```

NOTHING SHOWS

I really would appreciate the help. So basically I need to know how to query based on the child value and find the parent to that child. Thanks everyone.

Comment: My best bet would be debugging. Put the break point and open your console and do po

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things;

Your query is malformed. Ordered by defines what 'field' or node name you want to search.. it's the KEY part of the KEY:VALUE pair.

[fb queryOrderedByChild:@"person1 string"] should be

[fb queryOrderedByChild:@"node name to search"]

Let me break it down

Given

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Jay"
    state: "Florida"
  uid_1
    name: "Leroy"
    state: "Colorado"
```

and code

```
// a reference to the parent node we want to query
Firebase *usersRef = [self.myRootRef childByAppendingPath:@"users"];

//define which child node name we want to search
FQuery *statesRef = [usersRef queryOrderedByChild:@"state"];

//define the value we want to search for
FQuery *specificStateRef = [statesRef queryEqualToValue:@"Florida"];

[specificStateRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"snapshot:  %@", snapshot);
}];
```

snapshot will contain

```
  uid_0
    name: "Jay"
    state: "Florida"
```

The parent node name is uid_0 and can be retrieved with

```
NSLog(@" key: %@", snapshot.key);
```

and the name and state are key value pairs stored in the value

```
NSLog(@" value:  %@", snapshot.value);
```

Comment: Thank you Jay. If you don't mind I want to store the snapshot.value in a NSarray and I did that but outside the function  the NSArray goes to nil. So outside -----[specificStateRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"snapshot:  %@", snapshot);
}];     Once I leave here the values stored in the NSArray goes nill. Can we pass the snapshot value outside of this? Thank you so much!

Comment: If you define the array as a property of your class (which, if you are using it to populate a tableView, you should do anyway), you can refer to it as self.myArray, and then add snapshots, or snapshot.values (or any object) to it inside the block. It would only be nil if you defined the array within the block as variables defined within a block don't exist outside of the block - same is true for methods. Your comment (which is really a question) kinda goes outside the scope of the original question so you may want to craft up a new question (with code!) so we can address it.

Comment: Thanks Jay I will make a new question for it and put code. Thanks

Comment: If you are interested please check out my new question. Much appreciation    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36095098/ios-firebase-how-to-pass-snapshot-values-keys-outside-of-block