# iOS Firebase How to pass Snapshot values/keys outside of Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am really new to Firebase but I am beginning to like it. So I am having a problem with passing the values of snapshots outside the block.

I want to use NSStrings and or NSarrays to become the value of the snapshots. so that I can use them throughout the rest of my code.

Here is my code

```
NSString *string1;
NSArray *array1;
Firebase *usersRef = [fb childByAppendingPath:@"Parent name"];

FQuery *statesRef = [usersRef queryOrderedByChild:@"email"];

FQuery *specificStateRef = [statesRef queryEqualToValue:@"user name"];

[specificStateRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

   //NSLog(@"snapshot:  %@", snapshot);
   NSLog(@" key: %@", snapshot.key);
   NSLog(@" value:  %@", snapshot.value);
   //HELP ME HERE
   array1=[[NSarray alloc]initwithObjects:snapshot.value];
   string1=snapshot.key;

}];
```

So outside this block if I wrote.

```
    NSLog(@" String1 = %@", string1);
    NSLog(@" Array1 = %@", array1);
```

Unfortunately, the values of string1 and array1 both equal Nil. How can I get the values from Firebase and then be able to use them throughout the rest of the code. How can I get those values out of the block? Thanks y'all

Answer (score 0):

Now there's your problem:

> array1=[[NSarray alloc]initwithObjects:snapshot.value];

You are initializing your array within the block every time it runs.

Fixing is easy

outside the block (perhaps defined as a property, global var or __block)

```
@property NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray new];
```

inside the block

```
[myMutableArray addObject: snapshot.value];
```

One thing you also may be overlooking is that .childAdded events are called once for each child object and then for any new child objects after that.

So in this case if the parent node had three child nodes that matched the query, the block will be called three times, which is why we add each child within the block.

If you want to read in all of the results at the same time, you can use .value and then iterate over the results.

There's no right or wrong, it just depends on your use case. (.value could potentially read in thousands of results which may become a memory issue.)

See [Firebase Retrieving Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html) for specifics on .childAdded and .value.

Oh - one other note. Working with data outside the block that was retrieved inside the block can be tricky as the block will take time to complete. So, say for example, you're having a bad internet day and your speed is slow - the code outside the block may execute before the block has time to finish. So only address the data when you know the block has completed. (e.g. work with the data inside the block, set a completed flag or some other mechanic. In some cases .value makes this easier).

Comment: Hey Jay thanks. It sucks that I work outside the block, but what flag do you recommend? Because the values of integers or strings equals null when reading outside the block. so if inside the block I set the integer equal to 1, outside the block that value of the integer will not be equal to 1. So what flag mechanism do you recommend? This is hard so no worries if you don't have an answer, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Your comment is more of a swift/objc question and is answered in my answer; define the variables outside the block (like the array) and then set the values inside the block when data is returned from Firebase. So for example; if you want to fill an array as a dataSource for a tableView. Define the array outside the block, query for your data by .value. Then iterate over the snapshot (still within the block) filling the array, and then when done with that iteration, refresh the tableView.

Comment: I don't want a tableview. I really need to figure this out.

Comment: @user3352739 The mention of a tableView was an example of where you may want to use the data stored in the array. Your question asked about filling an array with snapshots and the answer demonstrates how to do that. Maybe that's not what you were asking?

Comment: @user3352739 It's also not clear where or how you will be working with the data outside the block. For example; You want to read in a series of numbers and then add them up. You read them by .value, iterate over the snapshots and add them up. That can all be done inside the block. You could also call a function to add them up from inside the block as well. Perhaps clarifying the question further would help us to help you.